# CMock's behaviour for IgnoreAndReturn

Tags: c, unit-testing, tdd, ceedling, cmock

I am currently trying to understand the intricacies of CMock's IgnoreAndReturn feature.

This is the function under test

```cpp
    void USBDriver_Exec(void)
    {
        uint8_t Val;
    
        // When the tx fifo is empty and we have tx data in the buffer, move data
        while (serial_writable(&USBDriver_serial) && (!Buffer_IsEmpty(&tx)) && (STATUS_OK == Buffer_Get(&tx, &Val)))
        {
            serial_putc(&USBDriver_serial, Val);
        }
    
        // When the rx fifo has data and the rx buffer isn't full, move data
        while (serial_readable(&USBDriver_serial) && !Buffer_IsFull(&rx))
        {
            Val = serial_getc(&USBDriver_serial);
            Buffer_Put(&rx, Val);
        }
    }
```

Now this is a sample of a test i am trying to write

```cpp
    void test_USBDriver_Exec_should_ReadBytes_when_BytesInBufferedAndReadable(void)
    {
        int i;
        uint8_t vals[5] = {'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'};
        serial_writable_IgnoreAndReturn(FALSE);
        Buffer_IsEmpty_IgnoreAndReturn(TRUE);
        Buffer_IsFull_IgnoreAndReturn(FALSE);
        serial_readable_IgnoreAndReturn(TRUE);
        for (i = 0; i < DIMENSION_OF(vals); i++)
        {
            serial_getc_ExpectAndReturn(&USBDriver_serial, vals[i]);
            Buffer_Put_ExpectAndReturn(&rx, vals[i], STATUS_OK);
        }
        serial_readable_IgnoreAndReturn(FALSE);
        USBDriver_Exec();
    }
```

whereby when i run the test, i get the test failure

[TestUSBDriver.c] Test: test_USBDriver_Exec_should_ReadBytes_when_BytesInBufferedAndReadable. At line (143): "Function Buffer_Put.  Called fewer times than expected."

Now, if i put serial_readable_IgnoreAndReturn() into the loop

```cpp
    void test_USBDriver_Exec_should_ReadBytes_when_BytesInBufferedAndReadable(void)
    {
        int i;
        uint8_t vals[5] = {'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'};
        serial_writable_IgnoreAndReturn(FALSE);
        Buffer_IsEmpty_IgnoreAndReturn(TRUE);
        Buffer_IsFull_IgnoreAndReturn(FALSE);
    
        for (i = 0; i < DIMENSION_OF(vals); i++)
        {
            serial_readable_IgnoreAndReturn(TRUE); //Line of interest
            serial_getc_ExpectAndReturn(&USBDriver_serial, vals[i]);
            Buffer_Put_ExpectAndReturn(&rx, vals[i], STATUS_OK);
        }
        serial_readable_IgnoreAndReturn(FALSE);
        USBDriver_Exec();
    }
```

The test passes! I am not exactly sure what to make of the error log and the [docs](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CMock/blob/master/docs/CMock_Summary.md) are not helping as it makes no sense under the ignore section. It is supposed to ignore any calls to func_IgnoreAndReturn and will return whatever i set. But it seems like i have to explicitly call it every loop if not a pedantic(?) error will throw

The version i am using is as follows:

Ceedling: 0.30.0
Unity: 2.5.1
CMock: 2.5.2
CException: 1.3.2